# How to find a formula for a non-obvious sequence of numbers?

Tags: sequences-and-series, pattern-recognition

Suppose I have an "arbitrary" sequence of numbers and as a convenience, I want some type of concise formula to be able to generate/regenerate that exact sequence.  How can I do it?  Can this be done for any sequence or are there limitations?  In math, can this "sequence generator" have a bunch of if statements to handle "sub-sequences" and/or erratic shifts?

Here is a sequence so how would I find a formula for this and in general, other similar sequences?

$200, 100, 50, 60, 75, 39, 15, 35$

Comment: Nothing prohibits your sequence continuing with any number. Say $(200,100,50,60,75,39,15,35,42,42,42,42,42,\ldots)$. Where did you get the sequence from? This may provide essential information to discovering a pattern. As far as general techniques go, there is hardly any one-for-all algorithm.

Comment: The sequence is not known to integer sequences, i.e., seems not to come from some reasonable rule. It is more or less arbitrary, and can be continued arbitrarily.

Comment: I made up this sequence as an example of "unpredictability" of the next term.  I realize the 9th, 10th... terms can be anything but I was just wondering about the first 8 terms how to find a closed form expression without a bunch of if statements to handle the erratic behavior.  You can assume the sequence is "locked" at length 8 so now I am asking for a formula to generate those 8 terms based on their position.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For any *finite* sequence of real numbers (as in your example), there is a formula that exactly reproduces it, e.g. an [interpolating polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation#Definition).

For your example sequence $[200,100,50,60,75,39,15,35]$ (indexed from $1$ to $8$), the lowest degree interpolating polynomial is

$$-\frac{163 x^7}{2520} + \frac{17 x^6}{9} - \frac{3947 x^5}{180} + \frac{9337 x^4}{72} - \frac{151531 x^3}{360} + \frac{55867 x^2}{72} - \frac{360187 x}{420} + 593
$$

which exactly reproduces the given sequence for $x=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8$.

Comment: reproduces it exactly or approximates it?

Comment: @David - The formula exactly reproduces the given finite sequence. [Try it online](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=interpolating+polynomial+calculator&f1=%7B200%2C100%2C50%2C60%2C75%2C39%2C15%2C35%7D&f=InterpolatingPolynomialCalculator.data_%7B200%2C100%2C50%2C60%2C75%2C39%2C15%2C35%7D&a=%2AFVarOpt.1-_%2A%2A%2AInterpolatingPolynomialCalculator.data--.%2A%2A%2AInterpolatingPolynomialCalculator.data2---.%2A--).

Comment: That is cool that the formula works but it is not simple.  Perhaps allowing a multiway formula would simplify it since the 2nd and 3rd terms follow a very simple pattern (50% of previous term).   Then we could just solve the subsequence $60, 75, 39, 15, 35$.  An even better example of where a "multibranch" formula is better is if the sequence has clear patterns such as $200, 100, 50, 60, 72, 36, 18, 27$.  First 3 terms are related (50% drop).  Next 2 are related (20% increase), next 2 are also 50% drop (so can be grouped with other related terms)....

Comment: Also I wanted to mention that these things can get very "ugly" like if you use this method to generate the first 20 decimal digits of pi.  There are other much more concise methods.

Comment: The polynomial form is called Lagrange Interpolation.  Wikipedia has an entry: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial    ; although their  explanation is overly complicated.  An interesting side note that is not mentioned is that if you set up the problem in matrix format you obtain the polynomial as the inverse of the Vandermonde matrix:)  Which in hindsight is obvious.  You can also generate the finite difference pyramid and then deconstruct it to a polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

To simplify it some we can "cheat" and do something like this:

A[1] = 200

A[2..3] = 1/2 A[x-1]

A[4..8] = -(31 x^4)/24+(281 x^3)/12-(3209 x^2)/24+(3259 x)/12-100

but plugging in 1 for sequence 4 (value 60), 2 for sequence 5 (value 75)...

$$-\frac{31 x^4}{24} + \frac{281 x^3}{12} - \frac{3209 x^2}{24} + \frac{3259 x}{12} - 100
$$

or (since the denominators are very similar to each other)

$$\frac{-31 x^4 + 562 x^3 -3209 x^2 + 6518 x}{24} - 100
$$